# How to fetch records based on from and end time in mysql

Tags: mysql, sqldatetime

I am facing one problem for fetching records from table. My table look likes below:-

```
id     market_id       opening_time       closing_time    day      p_slot
 1       1               06:30:00           09:30:00       Friday         1
 2       1               09:30:00           13:30:00        Friday         0
 3       1               17:30:00           19:30:00        Friday         0
 4       1               19:30:00           23:30:00        Friday         0
```

I want to filter data based on `opening_time` and closing time. I have tried below query

```
select * 
from `timing` 
where market_id = 1 
and day = 'Friday' 
and (opening_time <= '13:45:00' or closing_time <= '15:30:00') 
and (opening_time <= '15:30:00' or closing_time <= '15:30:00')
```

But when i run this query i got below response that is wrong

```
 id     market_id       opening_time       closing_time    day      p_slot
 1       1               06:30              09:30        Friday         1
 2       1               09:30              13:30        Friday         0
```

But yes if user search for below query then above output is correct

```
select * 
from `timing` 
where market_id = 1 
and day = 'Friday' 
and (opening_time <= '09:15:00' or closing_time <= '12:30:00') 
and (opening_time <= '12:30:00' or closing_time <= '12:30:00')
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue? I want result that exists in `opening_time` and `closing_time` range.

Note :- i want when user search with from time :- 9:15:00 and end time 12:30:00 i want to fetch 1st and 2nd rows only and if user search with 13:45:00 and 15:30:00 on that case i dont want any row to filter

Comment: Hi, what data type are your `opening_time` and `closing time` columns please

Comment: data type is time only 06:30:00

Comment: Why 2 exactly the same clauses specifying the times in  both queries?

Comment: @RiggsFolly check now

Comment: And do those queries, as they are now, still generate the rows you show us?

Comment: i want when user search with from time :- 9:15:00 and end time 12:30:00 i want to fetch 1st and 2nd rows only and if user search with 13:45:00 and 15:30:00 on that case i dont want any row to filter

Comment: You may need to put up a SQL Fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226147/discussion-between-kunal-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: @kunal Why not the 3d row for from time 9:15:00 and end time 12:30:00?

Comment: sorry that is getting duplicate by copying Apologies for that

Comment: i have updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition should be:

```
closing_time >= from_time and opening_time <= end_time:
```

Like:

```
select * 
from `timing` 
where market_id = 1 
and day = 'Friday' 
and closing_time >= '13:45:00' and opening_time <= '15:30:00';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e1d557d19d6fe7ead9f788ec67dc258e).

Comment: @kunal For which case it does not work? Post sample data where it does not work.

Comment: select * from `timing` where market_id = 1 and day = 'Friday' and closing_time >= '12:30:00' and opening_time <= '09:15:00' 
for  this request i want 1st and 2nd row but this query retursn empty

Comment: @kunal What you are doing is not my query. This is my query: `select * from timing where market_id = 11 and day = 'Friday' and closing_time >= '09:15:00' and opening_time <= '12:30:00'`

Comment: @kunal check the demo in my answer.

Comment: @kunal do you understand that you have to compare closing_time to fromtime and opening_time to endtime and not the opposite?